# Problem with appendix numbering

Tags: appendices

I have looked all questions about appendix but I could not solve my problem.
I am writing my thesis, composed of three chapters. In one chapter, I have an appendix. The problem is that I could not numbering it correctly.
For example, I get this for chapter 3 in the Contents:

...

3 The chapter three

3.1 Subsection of chapter 3

...

3.6 Conclusion

.1 Appendix

.1.1 The solution

But I want:

...

3.6 Conclusion

3.A Appendix

3.A.1 The solution

I am using this line in the main.tex file:

```
\usepackage[titletoc,title,header]{appendix}
```

Inside the chapter 3 tex file I have this:

```
\begin{appendices}
\section{Appendix}
\subsection{The solution}

    Blah Blah...

\end{appendices}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a minimal working example reproduing your problem?

Comment: You want \begin{subappendices} ,,, \end{subappendices}

Comment: Thanks Jonh. It's worked. But how to get rid of the word "Appendix" before the chapter number (Appendix 3.A Appendix)?

Comment: That is what the [titletoc] option does (add Appendix to the TOC).  Just remove it.  You know all these packages come with manuals?